# Log three failed login attempts

Tags: php

I need a script for logging login attempts: if a user attempts to login 3 times with the wrong password, then script will alert user to log in another way.

I tried this way but it's not working. How should I make this work? An explanation of the implementation of the code would also be appreciated.

```
public function log($usrname, $password, $type) {

    try {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username=:username and password =:password and type=:type");
        $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $usrname, ':password' => $password, ':type' => $type));
        $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($stmt->rowCount()== 1) {
            echo "loged in";
            } else if($stmt->rowCount == 0){
                $ec = 0;

                $error = ++$ec;
                if(count($error)== 3){
                    echo "you provide wrong username and password 3 times";
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: To achieve this, you've to maintain a session

Comment: but a session is not a good idea because it can simply clear from browser !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a 'attempt' field in the database table and each time you login with a wrong password just update the count into the table field and you can check the attempt count in the error condition. if the login is success just reset the attempt count to 0.

I've provide the code logic here. but I am not tested it. use this logic.

But I suggest you to check the username is registered with your table

```
 public function log($usrname, $password, $type) {

        try {

            $stmt0 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT username FROM $table WHERE username=:username");                
            $stmt0->execute(array(':username' => $usrname);
            if ($stmt0->rowCount()== 1) {

                  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username=:username and password =:password and type=:type");
                  $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $usrname, ':password' => $password, ':type' => $type));
                  $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                  if ($stmt->rowCount()== 1) {
                      echo "loged in";
                      // UPDATE THE attempt field to 0 here
                       $stmt2 = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE $table SET attempt=:attepmt WHERE username=:username");
                       $stmt2->execute(array(':username' => $usrname, ':attempt' => 0));

                  }else if($stmt->rowCount == 0){                    
                           // select the attempt field and check this is 3
                          $stmt3 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT attempt FROM $table WHERE username=:username");
                          $stmt3->execute(array(':username' => $usrname));
                          $obj= $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                          if($obj->attempt==3){                           
                              echo "you provide wrong username and password 3 times";
                          }
                      $attempt = $obj->attempt+1;
                      $stmt4 = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE $table SET attempt=:attepmt WHERE username=:username");
                      $stmt4->execute(array(':username' => $usrname, ':attempt' => $attempt));


                  }


            }else{
              echo "Username  is not  found in table !";
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$_SESSION` for counting the number of attempts.

```
public function log($usrname, $password, $type) {

    try {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username=:username and password =:password and type=:type");
        $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $usrname, ':password' => $password, ':type' => $type));
        $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($stmt->rowCount()== 1) {
            echo "loged in";
            } else if($stmt->rowCount == 0){
                if(isset($_SESSION['attempt']))
                 {
                   $_SESSION['attempt']=$_SESSION['attempt']+1;
                  }else {
                    $_SESSION['attempt']=1;
                  }
                $error = ++$ec;
                if($_SESSION['attempt']== 3){
                    echo "you provide wrong username and password 3 times";
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: but a session is not a good idea because it can simply clear from browser !

Comment: @Arun what are the chances user enter the correct username in your case.

Comment: he asked " if a user attempts to login 3 times with the wrong password, then script will alert user to log in another way " so in this case the username should be a valid one !. otherwise he have to print a message like user is not registered

Comment: @Arun where in the query you are checking the username is valid? i know what op asked.

Comment: hehe, well I am not doing all his homeworks !. let him do it ! :)

Comment: Hi Qaisar Satti, I provided the code to check the user is exist. kindly share your opinion :)

Comment: @Arun what you can do when username is not exists. i see your logic is fail there.

Comment: Qaisar Satti, can you tell me is there any logic to save a login attempt if there is no user account ?. yes of course this can be done by a session very simply. but session is easy to delete from browser na ?. pardon me if I am wrong :)

Comment: @Arun use new temp table for that and use `ip address` as a key then count the login attempt  and as for as  my solution concern it is quick solution.

Comment: yes I agree the temp table is a good idea :) but I do't believe the ip address  because of it's dynamic nature :) (only if need to keep the login attempt for the whole day.)